# Automatic conversion of three backslashes into two backslashes possible?

Tags: bug

In arrays in MathJax I needed always ***three*** backslashes to force a new-line; that was specific for MO and not so in MSE, for instance, where one needs only ***two***. Now that we are in the stackexchange network this is adapted; but the old three-backslash-answers are now broken, for instance my answer in: [Is $ \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^n / \sqrt{n!} $ positive?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84958/is-sum-limits-n-0-infty-xn-sqrtn-positive/85010#85010)

Can we do something about it, for instance one sql-formulation over the full database of questions, answers and comments?

*(Remark: this is different from the problem in [Double backslashes](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/238/double-backslashes) )*

Comment: Well, the symptoms manifest differently, but otherwise it seems to me this is exactly the same problem as in http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/238/double-backslashes .

Comment: @Emil: after reading the *whole* thread this looks indeed so... thanks for your comment

Comment: And indeed, this belongs on meta. Voting to migrate...

Comment: This question should be migrated to meta.mathoverflow.net. 